# Can't get the Android SDK Manager to work

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, android-studio, sdk

**Overview:**

- I cant open the SDK Manager. When I run it, the terminal shuts
  immediately.
- I can't open android.bat, it does the same thing as the SDK Manager.
- I can't open the layout in Visual Studio, it comes up with a long
  error about Java not being configured properly.

  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/utils/ILogger
      at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
      at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
      at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2774)
      at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
      at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
      at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.utils.ILogger
      at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
      at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
      at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
      ... 6 more
  Exception in thread "main"`

**Things I've Tried:**

- Reinstalled Android SDK command line tool. From memory I installed
  straight over the top of the current install.
- Reinstalled Android SDK With Android Studio IDE.
- I saw somewhere that the SDK won't work with JDK8, so I installed the
  most recent version of JDK7.
- Downloaded the Android SDK command line zip and copied the tools
  folder to the current Android SDK directory.

I've looked over countless articles for an answer. I'm thinking that it may be because I'm on Windows 10 Home, and not Pro which was has caused problems with Xamarin in the past - due to Home not having Hyper V(I think that's the name).

I owe my life / or a beer to whoever can help solve this.